# How can I create personalized menus in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, menuitem

I'm working on an XmlEditor (similar to XmlNotepad, but using WPF) in which I want to implement personalized menus. I.e. only show the most popular MenuItems on first open, and show all MenuItems when the user explicitly asks for it, either by clicking on the double arrow at the bottom or waiting for a certain amount of time.

I'm specifically looking for feedback on how I should approach this problem: any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: A bit behind the times?  Ditch the whole Office 2000 paradigm and go straight to the Ribbon.

Comment: I've thought about that before asking my question, especially since I've never been a big fan of personalized menus. However, in my XmlEditor, I have a popup menu that shows the allowable children. In case of flat XSDs, there may well be tens of dozens of them, scrolling of the screen, making the menus unwieldy. Using personalized menus would help, since I have no control over the XSD.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're working on an XmlEditor. It will be a problem for this case. Try using a different editor.